# No array2table in Octave

Tags: octave

I would like to have function `array2table` in Octave, same as there is in [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/array2table.html).

How to implement it? Any ready code snippet around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That function does not exist, Octave does not even have the table class which is very much recent in Matlab.

Instead, consider using [dataframe](http://octave.sourceforge.net/dataframe/index.html) which is based on R's data.frame design. Note that you will need to install Octave's dataframe package.